# Best front-end framework for mobile web app

Tags: meteor, frontend, yui-pure-css, materialize, material-design-lite

I am trying to develop an interactive web app for mobiles, and I want to give the best experience possible for the largest number of mobiles.

To do so I decided to go with meteor because it takes care of all the heavy lifting around the logic behind the scene, but such a choice come at a price, and on mobiles every kb transferred can get expensive depending on processor, network speed, etc.

So now I am trying to select a very tiny front-end framework to help giving the best experience with smallest loading time possible.

We have now various solution trying to tackle this problematic such as pure.css, min.css, base, materialize, material design lite, but I am having difficulties selecting the best solution:

- I do not always need the full set of funcionalities, so I should be able to build a subset easily
- I want the best looking possible interface at a minimum cost (weight)
- The package should handle well older browsers (mobile world is vast and furious)
- Small interactions should be handled well to give a nice look and feel
- The package should weight ideally at most 14kb to maintain a great experience without loading time on most phones and networks (More or less !!!)

So far I feel that material design lite is the best containder but what do you think ? Is it easy to customize (add social icons, remove unused icons, limit effects to very specific ones) ? Any other frameworks ? Better go without any framework and build interface from the ground ? Not worth the effort ?

Comment: [Recommended Reading](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

A lite framework sounds like the way to go.

Alternatively, you can use a task runner to eliminate unnecessary css in your files. The most popular grunt/gulp task seems to be these:

https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss

https://github.com/addyosmani/gulp-uncss-task

I have used these and they can greatly lower the size of your css files.